# Possible to debug every single event on a web page?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I am modifying a complex page. When it loads it redirects to another page if you are logged in.

I am able to put the `debugger;` JavaScript code on the page to stop it from redirecting. But when I step into the code, it shows absolutely nothing happening.

Is there anyway to just step through every single little event that happens on a page as the browser process it? So far it seems impossible.

Comment: Have you tried firebug?

Comment: I am using firebug. There is no option in firebug to break on every single thing the page does.

Comment: are you saying that after hitting the debugger command you can not step into the expected execution?

Comment: When I step in it just jumps to the end of the block. Does the placement of the debugger command matter? I put it in the first script that was already on the page. Should I put it at the top of the head?